# any obd dongle with the ability to stream live data ie CO2, HC and NOX?

Tags: obd

any obd dongle with the ability to stream live data ie CO2, HC and NOX ?

Comment: Cars don't have those sensors.  You can install them in the exhaust pipe, and use any communications protocol you please.

Answer (score 2):

No vehicle has sensors for CO2, HC and NOX. That's measured at the tailpipe with a 5-gas analyzer.